# Is there any method in hyperledger-fabric node sdk to get the list of all participating organisations in the network?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am writing an service where i need to get the list of all participating organisations. For now I have only one channel joined by all organisations but there may be a case where organisations joins different channels, Is there a way to get the list of all organisations participating in the network?

I found a method in Channel class which returns the channel's participating organisations.

Comment: As all the organizations must be the part of the system channel so if you found a method in channel class then you can just check for the system channel. It will return the list of all the participating organizations.